# For permissions payload, should I manually list actions or load actions programmatically from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions

In my Rails API app, I am sending a user's permissions payload which resembles:

```
{
    "permissions": {
        "payment": ["read", "create"],
        "order": ["read", "create", "update", "delete"]
    }
}
```

Here, payment can be said to be the controller (more likely to be called feature, and a feature may involve multiple controllers). "read", "delete" etc are actions. I am going to use the Pundit gem if you are familiar with it, although that is incidental.

I need a hash of all possible controllers (keys) and their actions (values) to build the full permissions hash. This will be needed in the permission management page, for example.

EDIT: Clarification - Any action being listed in the permissions payload of a user ( which is saved in the DB) means that it is permitted for that user. For examples if `permissions["order"]` return `nil` then that user will not have access to any OrdersController actions.

My question is: should I load all the controllers and their actions programmatically or should I list them manually. For example, I can do:

```
OrdersController.instance_methods(false)
```

Or in the OrdersController, I can have:

```
ACTION_LIST = ["read", "create", "update", "delete"]
```

Which do you think makes more sense and is more secure? Is there any loophole I am missing with this setup?

Comment: `OrdersController.instance_methods(false)` does all the actions from a controller are permitted always? There might be a role where only `show` is allowed..

Comment: Any action being listed in the permissions payload of a user ( which is saved in the DB) means that it is permitted for that user. For examples if `permissions["order"]` return `nil` then that user will not have access to any OrdersController actions. 

I will clarify this in the question itself.

Comment: ok, you didn't get my question...let's say `OrdersController.instance_methods(false)` this returns `["read", "create", "update", "delete"]`. Now there's a possibility that for various roles e.g. user and admin, user is only authorized to `read` and `create` but admin is authorized to do all. How would you handle this?

Comment: That depends on the `Role`. The permissions actually belong to `Roles` and a `User` can have several. And a Role's permission hash is saved in the DB. So, an Admin's permissions hash may have `"payment": ["read", "create"]` while a User's may have only `"payment": ["read"],`. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: if the `permissions` hash is already present in db, then you can directly do `current_user.role.permissions`